# Bootstrap responsive gallery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gallery

I'm trying to make responsive image gallery with Bootstrap. When I fetch 8 image from database, it works. But when I try fetch 18, I have a problem: empty places (no code, no divs, just empty places).

http://pl.tinypic.com/r/34yctfr/8

What can be wrong? I don't have any idea.

```php
<?php foreach ($gallery as $dane) { ?> 
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" >
            <a class="thumbnail morph" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/galeria_sub/'.$dane->plik) ?>" data-gallery>
             <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/galeria_sub/'.$dane->plik) ?>" alt="<?php echo $dane->opis;?>">
           </a> 
       </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

There are simple cols.

Comment: The image sizes are most likely to be different which will change padding etc... The image therefore pushed right to its next available spot. I've encountered this problem a few times with this layout, but hard to say for definite as you only have a picture.

Answer (score -1):

For responsive bootstrap 3 images you should try: https://github.com/mainseek/bilderoResponsive-Bootstrap3-Images

you save on storage, traffic and your images are responsive.